# Removing punctuation marks using ispunct()

Tags: c++, c

`ispunct()` works well when words are separated in this way `"one, two; three"`. Then it will remove ", ;" and replace with given character.

But if string is given in this manner `"ts='TOK_STORE_ID';"` then  it will take `"ts='TOK_STORE_ID';"` as one single token, or

`"one,one, two;four$three two"` as three tokens `1. "one,one" 2. "two;four$three" 3. "two"`

Is there any one so that `"one,one, two;four$three two"` could be considered as `"one one two four three two"` each separate token?

Writing manual code like:

```
for(i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
  //validating each character
}
```

This operation will become very costly when string is very very long.

So is there any other function like `ispunct()`? or anything else?

In c we do this to compare each character:

```
  for(i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
      if(str[i]==',' || str[i]==",") // Is there any way here to compare with all puctuations in one shot?
        str[i]=" "; //replace with space

    }
```

In c++ what is the correct way for this?

Comment: Is space a punctuation character; it shouldn't be.  Also, unless I'm missing something, `ispunct()` classifies single characters rather than editing a string as you seem to suggest in the first paragraph.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks, but if it classifies each character then `"two;four$three"` should be treated as two four three each seperately. But here it does not do it!

Comment: How exactly are you using `ispunct`? It doesn't modify a string or tokenize it. Is there anything wrong with [this result](http://ideone.com/V4CyCu)?

Comment: @molbdnilo: thanks dude, I am using in this way: `std::replace_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                 std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct), ' ');` may not be correct. Your code does what I want, but for that do I need to convert my `std::string input` to char array? or same thing could be done with string also?

Comment: You're confusing characters and strings.  These statements make no sense:  `str[i]==","` and `str[i]=" "`.  Also, why recompute the length of the string on ever iteration of the loop?  Call `str.length()` once, assign it to a variable, and use that instead.

Answer (score 5):

`This operation will become very costly when string is very very long.`

No, it won't. It will be an `O(n)` operation which is good for this problem. You cannot get better than this for this operation because any which way, you have to look at each and every character in the string. There is no way to do this without looking at each and every character in the string.

Comment: While dealing with big data, like data on social media or working with crawler which go through several webpage on web; Will it not take much time?

Comment: It doesn't matter how long it takes, the point is you can't do it faster. Unless you have structured data where you know in advance the positions of all the punctuation marks, how exactly do you propose to find them all without looking at every character in the string? There's no way for a program to just magically know where they are all.

Comment: @Karimkhan - if you have to traverse a string, then you cannot get better than O(n). You can optimize other stuff like removing the punctuation marks - but you have to traverse the string atleast once - there is no getting around that.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're dealing with a typical 8-bit character set, I'd start by building a translation table:

```
std::vector<char> trans(UCHAR_MAX);

for (int i=0; i<UCHAR_MAX; i++)
    trans[i] = ispunct(i) ? ' ' : i;
```

Then processing a string of text can be something like this:

```
for (auto &ch : str)
    ch = trans[(unsigned char)ch];
```

For an 8-bit character set, the translation table will typically all fit in your L1 cache, and the loop has only one branch that's highly predictable (always taken except when you reach the end of the string) so it should be fairly fast.

Just to be clear, when I say "fairly fast", I mean i's *extremely* unlikely that this would be the bottleneck in the process you've described. You'd need a combination of a slow  processor and fast network connection to stand any chance of this being the bottleneck in processing data you're obtaining over a network.

If you have a Raspberry Pi with a 10 GbE network connection, you *might* need to do a little more optimization work for this to keep up (but I'm not sure even then). For any less radical mismatch, the network is clearly going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @Karimkhan: No. `ch` is a reference to a single char in the string. The `for` loop walks through the string one character at a time, and transforms each character in turn. `ch` just gives access to the one being processed in a given iteration. The string being changed is `str`.

Comment: Thanks for explaination. `UCHAR_MAX` is what here?

Comment: It's the largest possible value for an `unsigned char` (in theory you should probably use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()`, but I find that just a bit wordy).

Comment: "8-bit character" you mean for programming or data I am processing? I am processing the content of various web page. Will it be ok?

Comment: @Karimkhan: are you reading the data as `char`s? If so, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
So is there any other function like ispunct()? or anything else?
```

As a matter of fact, there is. `man ispunct` gives me this beautiful list:

```
int isalnum(int c);
int isalpha(int c);
int isascii(int c);
int isblank(int c);
int iscntrl(int c);
int isdigit(int c);
int isgraph(int c);
int islower(int c);
int isprint(int c);
int ispunct(int c);
int isspace(int c);
int isupper(int c);
int isxdigit(int c);
```

Take whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `std::remove_copy_if` to remove the punctuation completely:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>      

  string words = "I,love.punct-uation!";
  string result;  // this will be our final string after it has been purified

  // iterates through each character in the string
  // to remove all punctuation
  std::remove_copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(),            
                    std::back_inserter(result), //Store output           
                    std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct)  
                   );

  // ta-da!
  cout << result << endl;
```